# Reversing list element in python

Tags: python, list, loops, numbers, reverse

How to reverse list element one by one in python?
I tried nested loop. But I couldn`t display second loop as "Result"

For example:

Input: `102 346 5897`

Result: `201 643 7985`

Comment: share your code.

Comment: What have you tried  ? [edit] and share it

Comment: read about and provide a [mre]

Comment: Jut try to revere it like this - [int(str(x)[::-1]) for x in lst] `lst` is your list.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your input list consists of strings, you go like this:

```
> a = ['102','346','5897']
> for i in a:
>    print(i[::-1],end=' ')
```

returns `201 643 7985`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following solution. you can use [::-1] to reverse a string.

```
x = ["123", "456", "789"]

y = []
for i in range(0,len(x)):
    y.append(x[i][::-1])
print(y)
['321', '654', '987']
```

You can use following trick with number inputs assuming inputs are numbers.

```
x = [123, 456, 789]
y = []
for i in range(0,len(x)):
    y.append(int(str(x[i])[::-1]))
print(y)
[321, 654, 987]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `[::-1]`

```
string='102 346 5897'
lst=string.split()[::-1]
print(' '.join(lst))
```

Comment: This does the wrong thing. Each individual word should be reversed, not the list of words.

Answer (score -1):

## You can use the built in function 'reverse()' instead of for loop (more efficient code) :

> code

```
def Reverse(lst):
   lst.reverse()
   return lst
  
lst = ["123", "456", "789"]
print(Reverse(lst))
```

> output

```
['789', '456', '123']
```

Comment: This does the wrong thing. The desired result is `['321', '654', '987']`.